# AWS EMR Spark not able to save table in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

Spark application is trying to save data to Hive table (S3 configured) but it is failing to access a "/tmp/hive" directory (in S3). I've set the below config and `.enableHiveSupport` on sparkSession object. All the EMR instance has access to read/write to the below bucket.

```
spark.sql.warehouse.dir
s3://smt-sessionizer-stage-out/spark/hive/metastore
```

Error:

```
23/01/05 17:44:52 INFO HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 2.3.7-amzn-4 using Spark classes.
23/01/05 17:44:52 INFO HiveConf: Found configuration file file:/etc/spark/conf.dist/hive-site.xml
23/01/05 17:44:52 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.thrift.url does not exist
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: tmp/hive/: PUT 0-byte object  on tmp/hive/: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 1BPCGWXXYGQ7Y6SE; S3 Extended Request ID: F12HhZZOLPEkok/MNvhXXLSJesYMMvmHCQbN+6XUetg2DzM8Iu1Oe0MjkjM160Mxg54FtEFLKS4=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: F12HhZZOLPEkok/MNvhXXLSJesYMMvmHCQbN+6XUetg2DzM8Iu1Oe0MjkjM160Mxg54FtEFLKS4=:AccessDenied
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:125)
```

Comment: try setting hive scratch and staging directory to same bucket as your warehouse.dir. example s3://smt-sessionizer-stage-out/spark/hive/metastore/tmp_hivescratch

Comment: @Raid I have tried that too, same error

Comment: it looks like your EMR doesn't have permission to write into the S3 bucket/path you specified as metastore.